# Como remover um branch remoto no Git?

Tags: git

Para deletar um branch local do Git, é só utilizar o comando `git branch -d <branch>`, mas como fazer com que este mesmo branch seja removido no servidor remoto?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Para remover um branch remoto, utilize o seguinte comando:

```
git push origin --delete <branch>
```

Note que este comando só funciona para o **Git v1.7.0** ou mais recente. Para versões mais antigas, utilize:

```
git push origin :<branch>
```

*Resposta inspirada [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2003515/604734) do Stack Overflow.*